# How to Find and Remove special Character in unix

Tags: shell-script

I have a large file. At the end of the file I have a special end of line character which is a small right arrow. The hexadecimal code for it is...&#x2192.

How would I look at the last line of the file and remove this small right arrows from the file.

I currently have a shell script that takes a file, unzips the file and then moves it to another file called MYFILE.TXT. I need to search the last line of MYFILE.TXT to see if that special character exists. If so then remove that character. If the character does not exist then do nothing to the file. Thank you for any help you may provide me

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say in what context you need to remove this character from the last line, but assuming you need to filter it out, have you tried something as simple as:

```
sed '$s/→//'
```

?

If you need to edit the file in place, the GNU implementation of `sed` has an easy in-place mode, which you can invoke with `-i`:

```
sed -i '$s/→//' file-to-edit
```

Use `-i ''` instead of `-i` in the `sed` of modern BSDs.

Comment: I currently have a shell script that takes a file, unzips the file and then moves it to another file called MYFILE.TXT. I need to search the last line of MYFILE.TXT to see if that special character exists. If so then remove that character. If the character does not exist then do nothing to the file. 

Thank you for any help you may provide me.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain this information instead of commenting on an answer.

Comment: Celada, Sorry I am new to this. I have edited my original question. Thank you.

Comment: sed -i '$s/→//' MYFILE.TXT > MYFILE.TXT this is the code I have but it is flagging me with an error stating the system does not recognize 'i'

Comment: sed -i '' '$s/→//' MYFILE.TXT > MYFILE.TXT I have this code now and unfortunately this flagged an error as well. Is the code I have correct?

Comment: `sed -i '..' file` already does in file replacements, no need for redirection with `> file` at the end. If `-i` really is not available, you might see for the `sponge` util: `sed '...' file | sponge file` to overwrite the file with stdout of the `sed` command.